# QtMobility camera on Symbian

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-mobility

Is it possible to show standard camera view (system camera view) using QtMobility on Symbian? I have Nokia N97. How can I show system camera view using QtMobility? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a QML/QtQuick friendly Qt wrapper for using the native Symbian camera application: http://juhaturunen.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-integrate-the-symbian-camera-application-to-a-qtquick-application/

I assume this is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might be help full, 
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0-beta2/multimedia.html